# I am flying overseas and returning with my fiancee. How do I coordinate the flights so that we are together on the return leg?

Tags: air-travel, international-travel, bookings

In the next two months I will be flying overseas to the Philippines to pick up my fiancee. I will be booking a round trip ticket, and will need to find a way to book her a ticket on the same route back as my return leg… but I can't seem to figure out a good way to do this.

Would I be better off booking two round-trip tickets, and let her seat fly empty for the trip there? Is this something where I would be better off using a travel agent instead of trying to book online or direct?

Comment: Couldn't you just book two one-way tickets separately for yourself and book one for her in the same order for the return ticket? A pair of one-way tickets is sometimes cheaper than a round-trip ticket anyway.

Comment: i dont believe so. it is my understanding that, because of philippine law, flights originating in the philippines can only be booked IN the philippines (eg, at a korean air office physically in the philippines, or with a philippine travel agent)

to be more clear i mean, a one way ticket originating in the philippines and not part of an onward itinerary that was already booked.

Comment: You can't do two round-trip tickets... as soon as she doesn't show up for the flight out there, they will cancel her entire trip.

Comment: is there no way to talk to the airline so that doesnt happen?

Comment: I think you have to describe your problem more clearly. I had no problems finding bookable one-way flights from Manila to Seoul (if that's where you are going) using the first arbitrary booking engine I though of, so there don't seem to be any legal restrictions when it comes to selling such tickets.

Comment: i have tried it and every time i get to the last stage of the booking, it does a geolocation and says i cant book outside the philippines (this occurred on kayak, as well as korean air and JAL's direct sites).

however, ignoring that, i still have the problem of coordinating the flights... that is to say i want to be sure we are on the same itinerary the whole way through on the leg from the philippines to america, and that's really the sticking point for me. after all, shes IN the philippines so dealing with the booking restriction isnt a problem, she can book. its the coordination.

Comment: The part about coordinating iteneraries is just to be careful of flight numbers and times... it's extra leg work, but quite possible using standard booking tools. The bit about the phillipines legal issue is a bit more challenging. How would you book her flight if you weren't going to fly together? Can you do the same for your own flight?

Comment: @flimzy, thats what i am thinking i am going to have to do: have HER book two tickets (one for me, one for her) on the same itinerary, and send me the ticket info so i can enter (because that would be my onward ticket), and i will just handle the ticket IN to the philippines.

Comment: @radio_babylon Why can't you just book yourself a round trip ticket and let your fiance book a one way trip. Coordinate with her such that these are on the same flight and then when you're *in* the Philippines you can check in with her. Most airports and airlines will be more than happy to put y'all together without any issues. I did the same when I was traveling from Delhi to New York with my parents. Our itineraries were different because I was leaving much later in comparison to them. And we were able to take the first flight together. I believe it should be OK with the flight back as well.

Answer (score 4):

I quite agree with **AdityaSomani**.

Usually when you check online, you can add *anyone* on the same flight to your check-in itenary, you only need their surname and Amadeus number. Just be carefull that sometimes available seats depend on the ticket vendor; once we weren't able to fly together just because some bought the tickets through a different website than others.

The very same thing applies for checking at the airport: they try to check a group together if the people come to the drop-off counter together. Just it's advised to be there in greater advance so that coupled seats are surely available.

*Therefore it should be sufficient to buy both tickets at the same place (either shop or e-shop), have both tickets in the same travel class, and do the check-in together.* Please remember that the cheapest option is often not available for one-way tickets, therefore getting the same class might be difficult. Because of this, I would recommend consulting an office before purchase.