# Traveling internationally with one-way airline tickets

Tags: visas, international-travel, philippines, one-way, proof-of-onward-travel

I am traveling to the Philippines from the US to see friends and travel for an unknown amount of time (between 3 months and  2 years). Everything I read says I need a roundtrip ticket. How do I get around that?

Comment: I believe it's related to visa requirements. I know how to obtain the travel visa, but I keep reading people needing round-trip airfare. I can't imagine that I am the only one that travels with an unknown return date. Does that make sense?

Comment: Book a fully refundable one-way ticket home, then cancel later?

Comment: @Gagravarr That is a good idea, but I just wanted to know if there is a correct way of doing this, without having money tied up in other airfare that I will cancel down the road. Also, it sorta seems like I am gaming the system that way.

Comment: Oh, okay. That makes sense. So, @pnuts , if I obtain a one-way ticket, but provide bank documents proving my ability to buy a return trip ticket in the future, I should be alright. Correct?

Comment: Or buy a cheap ferry ticket to Malaysia that you later throw away!

Comment: @ToddB. It depends on the country, look up “onward travel + name of the country” on this site or elsewhere to find out. No matter what the rules are, having an actual ticket (return ticket to your permanent home is best, but failing that even merely a cheap ferry/bus out of the country) could be easier than trying to argue about bank details with some foreign official.

Comment: [This discussion](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27096/i-am-flying-overseas-and-returning-with-my-fiancee-how-do-i-coordinate-the-flig) also suggests that there are some funky rules regarding one-way tickets originating in the Philippines. It might not be possible to buy them from your usual online agent.

Comment: @Relaxed - Thanks for the info and the links. As of right now, I am looking only to buy a flight from the United States to the Philippines. 6 months later, if the Philippines requires me to buy my one way ticket while I am in the Philippines, that will work.

Comment: @Gagravarr - Ferry to Malaysia should be quite cheap. That may be the most affordable workaround.

Comment: I don't really know, to be honest. The best would be to add all this info (that you are concerned about onward travel requirements, whether having money instead of a ticket is enough, whether it needs to be a return flight or simply a cheap ferry) to the question and hopefully someone who went there will provide more details.

Comment: Here is a good post regarding onward travel (a term that I wasn't very familiar with until this post) requirements in the Philippines.  https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/asia-south-east-asia-islands-peninsula/topics/recent-experience-onward-ticket-update-for-entering-the-philippines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing where you are flying from originally and what time of year, you may find that a discounted round trip ticket is just as cheap as a one way.  Which would cover your visa and entry needs.  And depending on the fare class, you maybe able to change the return date, once you figure out how long you are staying (in worse case you throw away the return portion's value but do cancel the return booking).

You could also look at more expensive round trip airfares that allow date changes.  Though if you stay a long time you could find the original fare no longer applicable and you would have to pay the fare difference when you changed dates.

Another option is the proverbial throw away ticket, find some really dirt cheap flight to any country outside the Philippines and buy a ticket.

Or the other extreme, buying a fully refundable airfare, then cancelling it and getting your money back.

Comment: I've actually found round-trip tickets to the Philippines from the U.S. to be frequently _cheaper_ than one-way tickets for the same city pairs. Air fares can be a very strange thing.